# How do I split email address/password string in two in Python?

Tags: python, parsing, split

Lets say we have this string: `[18] email@email.com:pwd:`

`email@email.com` is the email and `pwd` is the password.

Also, lets say we have this variable with a value

```
f = "[18] email@email.com:pwd:"
```

I would like to know if there is a way to make two other variables named `var1` and `var2`, where the `var1` variable will take the exact email info from variable `f` and `var2` the exact password info from `var2`.

The result after running the app should be like:

```
var1 = "email@email.com"
```

and

```
var2 = "pwd"
```

Answer (score 9):

```
>>> var1, var2, _ = "[18] email@email.com:pwd:"[5:].split(":")
>>> var1, var2
('email@email.com', 'pwd')
```

Or if the "[18]" is not a fixed prefix:

```
>>> var1, var2, _ = "[18] email@email.com:pwd:".split("] ")[1].split(":")
>>> var1, var2
('email@email.com', 'pwd')
```

Comment: Nice, I was going to suggest two splits.  What's the [4:] syntax called?

Comment: Thanks.  After Googling that term it seems like it's rather fundamental in Python.  I guess I need to add "Learning Python" to my stack of books to read.

Answer (score 7):

```
import re
var1, var2 = re.findall(r'\s(.*?):(.*):', f)[0]
```

If findall()[0] feels like two steps forward and one back:

```
var1, var2 = re.search(r'\s(.*?):(.*):', f).groups()
```

Comment: May also want to add in match checking. For instance, if the re.search returns None, then you'll get a nice little error for trying the groups() method on a NoneType object. All in all, a good solution though PEZ. +1

Comment: `re.search(r'\s([^:\s]+):([^:\n]*):')`

Comment: Thanks, Evan. I think also the findall() needs a check for length before you try to index it if the data isn't "cleaned" beforehand.

Comment: @J.F. It depends on the application and the data. You're expression will extract "mail.com" as the address if the string is "[18] email@e mail.com:pwd:". It might, and might not, be what's requested. We don't know. I prefer to make weaker assumptions on the data and stronger on the format.

Comment: Second `.*` in your regexp will eat all but last ':'. It certainly doesn't respect format. I've never encountered cases where spaces in email were accepted. It is reasonable to assume that newline is not in password.

Comment: What's to say there are only valid e-mail addresses or passwords in the data?

Answer (score 5):

```
var1, var2 = re.split(r'[ :]', f)[1:3]
```

Answer (score 1):

To split on the first colon ":", you can do:

```
# keep all after last space
f1= f.rpartition(" ")[2]
var1, _, var2= f1.partition(":")
```